# Treat Wounds DC under Proficiency without Level

Tags: pathfinder-2e, healing, optional-rules

Using the rules for [Proficiency without Level](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1370), what is the DC for [Treat Wounds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=57)?

I assume the base DC would stay at 15, which makes things harder for PCs but not too hard, but what about the option to increase the DC to heal more? Under those rules a DC or 40 isn't reachable, even for a legendary healer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Normal Treat Wounds uses Simple DCs, so use the adjusted Simple DCs for PWL.

The typical [Treat Wounds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=57) DC modifications follow the same table as the [Simple DCs](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=553) offered in the Core Rulebook. [Proficiency Without Level](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1370) provides adjusted Simple DC tables.

This would make the normal Treat Wounds DC still 15, with Expert at 20, Master at 25, and Legendary at 30. A character with high modifiers at level 15 could be expected to have around a +14 or +15 in their Medicine skill (+8 from proficiency, +4 or +5 from their Wisdom and a +2 item bonus from some [Greater Healer's Gloves](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=444)), making the DC 30 check very difficult, but not impossible, especially if they get a circumstance bonus from Aid or Risky Surgery or a status bonus from a spell.

Ultimately, there aren't hard and fast rules for how to integrate every rule into Proficiency Without Level. You may want to start with these DCs as a baseline and adjust them down if they feel too high. For example, using the Easy (-2) adjustment for Treat Wounds gives the same example character mentioned above a base 35% chance of success on their Legendary medicine check instead of a base 25% chance.

Comment: It looks to me like it makes things way harder than they are for PCs who add their level. At level 15 for example this same character would have +30 on their check, which let them succeed on 10 or higher (while without level it is on 15 or higher). Moreover, 15 is the only high-level with so low of a gap: at lvl 14 you need 12 to succeed without level but only 3 with level.

Comment: That does seem to be in keeping with the stated design for PWL - they mention that "The new DCs make it a little harder for high-level characters to succeed than it would be when using the default numbers from the Core Rulebook." For something closer to the standard success chance I'd probably use a curve of 15 -> 18 -> 22 -> 26 or so.

Comment: I don't think getting an equivalent to +10 to the difficulty at some levels qualifies as "a *little* harder".